# How to create rar file in parts using SevenzipLib?

Tags: c#

How to compress a file into parts for example: test001.rar, test002.rar ..., each part of 100mb each using seven zip library?

Comment: It can't - it can only unpack rar files, it can't pack them. The RAR people only release unpacker source with a licence forbidding reverse-engineering into a packer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7-Zip cannot create RAR archives at all, let alone in parts.

All it can do is extract them:

http://www.7zip.com/type/3/RAR

Also see the front page for that library:

http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/

> **Supported formats**
>   **Packing / unpacking**: 7z, ZIP, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, XZ
>   **Unpacking only**: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, DEB, DMG, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MSI, NSIS, **RAR**, RPM, UDF, WIM, XAR, Z, XZ, and more.

As for your second question, if there are any other C# libraries that support the ability to create RAR files, see [this article describing the commercial-only nature of the software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR#Software):

> RAR files may be created only with commercial software WinRAR, RAR, and software that has permission from the licensor Alexander Roshal (Eugene's brother).  RAR for Pocket PC is the only freeware for creating RAR files.

If you can stomach it, 7-zip is a much better file format anyhow, and it is Free and Open Source Software...

Comment: is there any library that can create rar files in parts in c#?

Comment: Is there any way that I can create "rar" files from directory in parts using any library in c#?

Comment: @Arun: This library seems to support compressing to some form of RAR archive, though given the nature of the articles I've just read, it sounds like it is a legal grey area, so I wouldn't build anything important off this library: http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/releases/view/73754

Comment: @ArunKumar: If you really want to do this, a safer way would be to wrap the command line version of RAR with your own C# code, using `Process.Start`.  It would require users to have a demo version or license for the software though.

Comment: ok I will use 7zip format to compress directory, but I need to know is it possible to create 7zip file in parts, because I need to upload it to the server where there is restriction of max size 100mb, Can you help me with some code that can compress file in 7zip format in parts using sevenzip lib?

Comment: @Arun: If you write it, I can help you when you get stuck.  Feel free to post specific questions on areas where you are having problems.  [The main page for `SevenZipLib`](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/) has really easy to follow sample code to get your started.

Comment: string sevenzip  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["7zippath"].ToString();

           SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(sevenzip);
           SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor Compress = new SevenZipCompressor(sFilePath);
           Compress.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;
           Compress.CompressDirectory(sFilePath, "Zip.7zip");

Comment: I have written this code it successfully creates the 7zip file but it doesnot create 7zip files in parts, I need to know how it is possible to create 7zip files in part?

Comment: @Arun: As I said earlier, if you get stuck you should post a *separate* SO question for it.  Also, if you my answer addressed your original question about RAR files, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to programatically make rar files (splitted or not) is to buy a license:

Un-rar-ing a file programatically is available for free (SharpZipLib does it for example).

rar-ing a file programatically is licensed.